# JSON - Return Property Count

Tags: json

**JSON structure:**

```
{
    "codes":[
        {   
                "id":"1",           
                "code":{                
                    "fname":"S",
                    "lname":"K"

            }
        },
        {   
                "id":"2",               
                "code":{                
                    "fname":"M",
                    "lname":"D"                 
            }
        }
]
}
```

**I want to loop through each code and alert the number of properties within each code**

```
    success: function(data){
        var x, count=0;
        for (x = 0; x < data.codes.length; x++){
            for (property in data.codes[x].code) {
                count++;
                alert(count);                           
            }                   
        }       
    }
```

**The above works BUT it returns 4 as the `count`. It should return 2 for each `code`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that code is an object not an array. You can loop over the properties of an object like this:

```
success: function(data){
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < data.codes.length; x++){
        var count = 0;
        for (property in data.codes[x].code) {
            count++;
            alert(count);                           
        }                   
    }       
}
```

Comment: It seems you responded as I updated my post. I'm looping through the object and I'm getting `count` = 4. For each `codes` > `code`, it should return 2. Can you pls help?

Comment: I count 4: codes[0].fname, codes[0].lname, codes[1].fname, codes[1].lname

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I want. I want to print the number of properties in each `code` and each `code` has only 2 properties - (1) fname (2) lname

Comment: Would you know how to resolve this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125087/json-checking-for-a-property-in-a-deeply-nested-json