# JSON - Checking for a property in a deeply nested JSON

Tags: json

JSON structure:

```
{
    "codes":[
        {   
                "id":"1",           
                "code":{                
                    "fname":"S",
                    "lname":"K",
                    "dateofbirth":{
                        "month":"12",
                        "day":"02",
                        "year":"1998"
                    }

            }
        },
        {   
                "id":"2",               
                "code":{                
                    "fname":"M",
                    "lname":"D",
                    "dateofbirth":{
                        "month":"10",
                        "day":"02",
                        "year":"1998"
                    }                 
            }
        }
]
}
```

I want to loop through each `code` **AND** `dateofbirth` and alert if the `month` is 12. If the `month` is **not** 12, then do nothing.

```
    success: function(data){
        var x;
        for (x = 0; x < data.codes.length; x++){
            var count=0;
            for (property in data.codes[x].code) {
                count++;                                               
            }                   
        }       
    }
```

**How can I loop through `dateofbirth` and check for the value of `month`?**

**Example of JSON structure with more than 1 property under 'code' that can be an object**. So I want to loop through all the properties within `code` and check for the value of the `month` property instead of manually checking for a particular property.

```
    {
        "codes":[
            {   
                    "id":"1",           
                    "code":{                
                        "fname":"S",
                        "lname":"K",
                        "dateofbirth":{
                            "month":"12",
                            "day":"02",
                            "year":"1998"
                        },
                        "membership":{
                            "month":"12",
                            "day":"12",
                            "year":"2011"
                        }        
                }
            },
            {   
                    "id":"2",               
                    "code":{                
                        "fname":"M",
                        "lname":"D",
                        "dateofbirth":{
                            "month":"10",
                            "day":"02",
                            "year":"1998"
                        },
                        "membership":{
                            "month":"10",
                            "day":"12",
                            "year":"2011"
                        }                
                }
            }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Your goals are not consistent: "How can I loop through dateofbirth and check for the value of month?", "I want to loop through all the properties within code instead of manually checking for a particular property." I'm not clear on what you want.

Comment: Jonathan - I updated my JSON structure for you so that It's more clear on what I want to do. Just to re-iterate, I want to loop through each `code` and then each property within `code` that is an object and has the property `month`. If **a** property within `code` is an object and in turn has a property `month`, I want to alert `month`. Hope it's clear!

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear before.

Answer (score 2):

```
mycodes=// the object from parsed JSON

for (i=0; i<mycodes.codes.length; i++) {
    if (mycodes.codes[i].code.dateofbirth.month=="12") {
        alert("Code " + mycodes.codes[i].id + " has birth month of 12");
    }
}
```

BTW, you really should store birthdates as numbers, not strings.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it worked. **BUT**, I want to loop through all properties of `code` since there can be more than 1 `code` property that is an object. I will update my JSON to show what I mean.

Comment: I have. It's just that I added the comment first and then updated my post, specifically JSON. Sorry about that.